# How to use vuex getter inside the onMounted method in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex, vue-composition-api

I fetch data from a database that I sore in vuex. I retrieve it with a getter in the setup method but I'd like to use some of that data before the page is rendered, preferably in the onMounted method. I don't know how to do it using the Compositions API. Here's my code:

```
setup() {
   const store = useStore();

   //store.dispatch(Actions.LOAD_COMMUNITY);
   onMounted(() => {
     store.dispatch(Actions.LOAD_COMMUNITY);
     setCurrentPageTitle(this.community.communityName);
   });

   return {
     community: computed(() => store.getters.currentCommunity),
   };
 },
```

When I do it like that, I get a " Cannot find name 'community' " error and I can't fix it by using this.community.

I'd appreciate it if you guys could help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` isn't supposed to be used with composition API and `setup`. Component instance isn't available in `setup` but can be accessed with `getCurrentInstance()` in special cases.

It should be:

```
   const community = computed(() => store.getters.currentCommunity),

   onMounted(() => {
     ...
     setCurrentPageTitle(unref(community).communityName);
   });

   return { community };
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. After implementing it, I get the error: "Property 'communityName' does not exist on type 'ComputedRef<any>'". Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: This is TS error that indicates an existing problem. It's a ref and should be treated as such. Also in your code you treat the action like it's sync while in reality it's likely async.